# Listar parte de um arquivo JSON usando C#

Tags: c#, json

Por questões de erros com uma versão do Windows acabei não trabalhando com bancos de dados e passei a utilizar arquivos `JSON`. Porém eu preciso carregar somente parte dos itens (Lista) para um `DataGridView` de acordo com o "tipo" que eu seleciono em um `ComboBox`. Para isso estou utilizando o laço condicional `switch`:

```
public class LotofacilQuantidades
{       
    public int CONC { get; set; }
    public string DATA { get; set; }
    public int SOMA { get; set; }
    public int qPAR { get; set; }
    public string PAR { get; set; }
    public int qIMP { get; set; }
    public string IMPAR { get; set; }
    public int qREP { get; set; }
    public string REPETIDO { get; set; }
    public string INICIAL { get; set; }
    public string FINAL { get; set; }
    public int qFIB { get; set; }
    public string FIBONACCI { get; set; }
    public int qNP { get; set; }
    public string PRIMOS { get; set; }
    public int qINP { get; set; }
    public string INP { get; set; }
    public int qMD { get; set; }
    public string MOLDURA { get; set; }
    public int qSQ { get; set; }
    public string SEQUENCIA { get; set; }
    public int qITV { get; set; }
    public string INTERVALO { get; set; }
    public int qX { get; set; }
    public string XIS { get; set; }
    public int qL01 { get; set; }
    public string LINHA_01 { get; set; }
    public int qL02 { get; set; }
    public string LINHA_02 { get; set; }
    public int qL03 { get; set; }
    public string LINHA_03 { get; set; }
    public int qL04 { get; set; }
    public string LINHA_04 { get; set; }
    public int qL05 { get; set; }
    public string LINHA_05 { get; set; }
    public int qC01 { get; set; }
    public string COLUNA_01 { get; set; }
    public int qC02 { get; set; }
    public string COLUNA_02 { get; set; }
    public int qC03 { get; set; }
    public string COLUNA_03 { get; set; }
    public int qC04 { get; set; }
    public string COLUNA_04 { get; set; }
    public int qC05 { get; set; }
    public string COLUNA_05 { get; set; }
}
```

O que preciso é desserializar o arquivo `JSON` pegando somente o "CONC", "DATA" + o tipo que foi determinado no `ComboBox` e sua quantidade correspondente. Ex: case : "IMPAR" ele me traria a lista com "CONC", "DATA", "IMPAR", "qIMP".
Algo tipo:

```
 //busco o arquivo json
 var _arq = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Relatorio.json");

 //listo o arquivo
 List<LotofacilQuantidades> _lstFinal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LotofacilQuantidades>>(_arq);
 //seleciono os itens que pretendo utilizar com o switch/case (aqui está meu erro/problema)
 var teste1 = _lstFinal.Select(c => c.CONC && c.DATA && c.FINAL).ToList();
```

Nesse caso só é permitido listar um item com o Select.

Comment: 1- o SO não é um fórum. 2- acesse o [Tour] para entender 3- basta vc fazer um if e retornar o select de acordo com a condição q vc precisa... e não precisa ficar lendo o arquivo json toda vez... o select deveria ser... `.Select(c => new { c.CONC, c.DATA, c.Final });`

Comment: Ok Rovann. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo usando um combobox, e ao alterar o combo é realizado o select:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista.Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.Propriedade1 }).ToList();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista.Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.Propriedade2 }).ToList();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista.Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.Propriedade3 }).ToList();
    }
    else
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
}
```

Classe Modelo:

```
public class Modelo
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Propriedade1 { get; set; }
    public int Propriedade2 { get; set; }
    public int Propriedade3 { get; set; }
}
```

Obs: O datagridview está para gerar as colunas automaticamente.